# How to select records present in one table which are not present in another table knowing that records can be kept in multiple fields

Tags: sql, left-join, union, ms-access-2016

This question might have been asked already, but I haven't seen it. I need it for quality control purposes. One table is with the respondents we should send emails to, and the other one is the list of respondents who have unsubscribed, or who we have blacklisted. 
There is a possibility that a respondent can have records in both tables (for example we have some email in the Respondents Email column, and the exact same email in the Unsubscribers Email 2 column etc.)

**Table Respondents**:
Name
Surname
Email
Email 2
Phone
Phone 2

**Table Unsubscribers**:
Name
Surname
Email
Email 2
Email 3
Email 4
Phone

Comment: I don't actually see your question here (or in the title).  What do you want to do with these two tables?

Comment: add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Sorry for poor formatting.<br/>
Here are the tables, and as you can see, I want to exclude jj@smith.com from the end table<br/>

**Table Respondents**<br/>
Name Surname Email Email 2 Email 3 Phone<br/>
John Smith jj@smith.com jsmith@gmail.com  123456789<br/>
Maggie Bell mbell@something.com   654321987<br/>
<br/>
*Table Unsubscribers*<br/>
Name Surname Email Email 2 Email 3 Phone<br/>
Peter Smalling p.s@yahoo.com   <br/>
Pau Gasol p.gasol@spain.com   <br/>
J Smith rudy.fernandez@spain.com jj@smith.com<br/>

Comment: @AleksandarIlijevski - you can edit your own post. See edit link at bottom. Please delete this comment and adjust.

Comment: @Parfait, tried copying it directly from table, and after that with the <br/>, can't do anything about it. However, I thing Gordon understood the question quite well, thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it.

`SELECT email from respondents LEFT JOIN unsubscribers u1 ON respondents.email = u1.email JOIN unsubscribers u2 on respondents.email = u2.email2 WHERE u1.email is null and u2.email2 is null`

However, I would try to normalize your database. In your instance I would just add a date_unsubscribed field to the respondents table, it makes this sort of thing way easier and reduced database complexity and storage requirements.

Comment: Good attempt but query is not compliant in MS Access as `JOIN` must be specific and parentheses must be used in multiple joins.

Comment: Oh, missed the ms-access tag, just saw sql.

Answer (score 0):

`NOT IN` would be a typical approach:

```
select r.*
from respondents as r
where r.email not in (select email from unsubscribers) or
      r.email not in (select email2 from unsubscribers) or
      r.email not in (select email3 from unsubscribers) or
      r.email not in (select email4 from unsubscribers) or
      r.email2 not in (select email from unsubscribers) or
      r.email2 not in (select email2 from unsubscribers) or
      r.email2 not in (select email3 from unsubscribers) or
      r.email2 not in (select email4 from unsubscribers);
```

Comment: @Parfait . . . `OR` because only one has to match.  As for `email2`, I added that in.